# How to process SNMP traps with Sensu?

Tags: snmp, system-monitoring, sensu

We are evaluating monitoring systems with Sensu being one of the candidates. One requirement we have is processing of the SNMP traps.

My searches come up with Sensu-extensions only, but the extensions are from third parties and not even available via `gem`.

Can Sensu process SNMP traps -- either out of the box or with a common and free extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appear to be two primary open and free methods for accepting SNMP traps via Sensu:

- https://github.com/warmfusion/sensu-extension-snmptrap
- https://github.com/cloudant/sensu-trapd

They both appear to operate in a similar manner (by receiving SNMP and translating the source of the message into a Sensu Just In Time Client, and creating a Sensu event from the message.